# How do I get this JavaScript program to alert an object property based on the input from a prompt?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, alert, prompt

I'm trying to get the program to alert the capital when the user inputs the state abbreviation.  When the program prompts the user to enter the abbreviation, if he enters ME, the program should alert Augusta.  I know I'll need to add a toUpperCase somewhere, but I'm not worried about that now.  Right now the program just alerts undefined.  I thought that by using "input" as my var for the prompt, it would allow me to make somewhat of a universal program for the alert without having to create specific alerts for every possibility.  How can I fix this?

```
    var capitals = {
        ME: "Augusta", 
        NH: "Concord", 
        VT: "Montpelier", 
        MA: "Boston", 
        CT: "Hartford", 
        RI: "Providence"
    };

    var input = prompt("Enter the postal abbreviation for a New England state:");

    alert(capitals.input);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ScY73/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `capitals[input]`. You are checking for the actual `input` property with your usage, which is of course undefined. To access properties of an object with a variable, always use [ ] notation.

Comment: Incidentally bracket notation is also how to get and set properties with wacky names like '!WOAH!' (though that is usually bad practice unless you have a good reason).